# form submission with file upload/download

Tags: jquery, ajax, download, flask, forms

I want to make a webpage allow user to upload certain types of files. The server will in return another file based on the uploaded file while providing a summary report using json.

Currently I'm using `flask` at backend and `jquery` at front end. Right now I have two buttons. One for upload files. `Flask` returns a `sendfile` which sends the file to user as attachment. Another button triggers an `ajax` request. `Flask` returns a `json` file which contains the summary of the returned file. Both the returned file and the `json` file are stored in databse.

My question is that is it possible to combine those two buttons into one? ie, allow user to download the file and view the summary after clicking only the uplaod button? I'm new to front end and it seems to me that the only way to do this is to make both request `ajax`. And since file download can't be done with `ajax`, it's not doable to combine those two buttons?

Comment: Can post `html` , `js` ?

Answer (score 0):

Use This

You can upload files with ajax function without loading the page.

[Click here For Demo and Code](http://www.formget.com/ajax-image-upload-php/)

Comment: That's not quite i want. My upload doesn't reload the page already. What i want is to allow the user to receive the file and get a summary which is a json file sent from the server.

Comment: You can return file array as custom array as a result.